# Is there any way to get GPU information?

Tags: android, gpu

I know how to get CPU info inside `/proc/`, but is there any way to get GPU info? Something like the CPU one?

Comment: Seriously you down voted without saying nothing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is, you can get GPU information by using OpenGL:

```
    Log.d("GL", "GL_RENDERER = "   + gl.glGetString( GL10.GL_RENDERER   ));
    Log.d("GL", "GL_VENDOR = "     + gl.glGetString( GL10.GL_VENDOR     ));
    Log.d("GL", "GL_VERSION = "    + gl.glGetString( GL10.GL_VERSION    ));
    Log.i("GL", "GL_EXTENSIONS = " + gl.glGetString( GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS ));
```

For more information see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

Comment: here it is:

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html

Comment: I'm sorry but, could you please explain how to declare that gl in an `Activity`?

Comment: thanks for the help, i try it but gl Unidentified How to set gl

Answer (score 23):

Simpler way:
adb shell dumpsys | grep GLES

Comment: A slightly modified version `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger |grep GLES` take less time to run

Comment: One thing to note though is that this `dumpsys` command runs only within a command-line ADB shell and does not run programmatically because only system apps have access to it.

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger | grep GLES`  in PowerShell （Windows 10）

Answer (score 4):

Here is a SampleActivity to get GPU info:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{
    private TextView textView;
    private GLSurfaceView glSurfaceView;
    private StringBuilder sb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        final ActivityManager activityManager =  (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager
                .getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
        sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("GL version:").append(configurationInfo.getGlEsVersion()).append("\n");

        textView.setText(sb.toString());
        this.glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        this.glSurfaceView.setRenderer(this);
        ((ViewGroup)textView.getParent()).addView(this.glSurfaceView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
       sb.append("RENDERER").append(gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_RENDERER)).append("\n");
        sb.append("VENDOR").append( gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_VENDOR)).append("\n");
        sb.append("VERSION").append(gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_VERSION)).append("\n");
        sb.append("EXTENSIONS").append(gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS));
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.setText(sb.toString());
                glSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect example to get GPU information. How can I implement the same in a java library project which is being included as jar file in android application.

Comment: You can't do it with JAR (Java archive) because it requires Android SDK. you can develop it as an Android Library module (AAR) instead.

Comment: I implemented this. It works. But on some devices, it gives this error. 
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
createContext failed: EGL_BAD_ALLOC

Answer (score 3):

I hope its useful useful to you..
    First This code check if device is support the GPU or Not.

```
 // Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
  final ActivityManager activityManager =  (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager
            .getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

    if (supportsEs2) {
        Log.i("JO", "configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion:"
                + configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion + "supportsEs2:"
                + supportsEs2);
        // Request an OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible context.
        myGlsurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        // Set the renderer to our demo renderer, defined below.
        myRenderer = new MyRenderer(this, myGlsurfaceView);
        myGlsurfaceView.setRenderer(myRenderer, displayMetrics.density);
        myGlsurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    } else {
        // This is where you could create an OpenGL ES 1.x compatible
        // renderer if you wanted to support both ES 1 and ES 2.
        return;
    }
```

Second One : This code give the GPU Information..

Put It in this code inside MyRenderer Class..

```
 public void determineGraphicSupport(GL10 gl){
    int _graphicEngine = GRAPHICS_CANVAS;

    String extensions = gl.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS); 
    //String version = GLES10.glGetString(GL10.GL_VERSION);
    String version = GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION);

    //String renderer = gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_RENDERER);
    String renderer = GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_RENDERER);

    boolean isSoftwareRenderer = renderer.contains("PixelFlinger");
    boolean supportsDrawTexture = extensions.contains("draw_texture");

    int[] arGlMaxTextureSize = new int[1];

    gl.glGetIntegerv( GLES20.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, arGlMaxTextureSize, 0 );

    if( !isSoftwareRenderer && supportsDrawTexture && _width >= 480 && _height >= 800 
            && arGlMaxTextureSize[0] >= 4096 )
        _graphicEngine = GRAPHICS_OPENGL_DRAW_TEXTURE;
    else
        _graphicEngine = GRAPHICS_CANVAS;

 }
```