# Need to display Graphic driver details in java?

Tags: java, swing, gpu, sigar

Looking for some api to display graphics driver details in `java`.
I have searched in `Sigar` but couldn't find? is it possible with `sigar`? is there any other cross-platform API just to display the `gpu` info?

I want to display the Graphics driver information in a Swing application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to get GPU information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804365/is-there-any-way-to-get-gpu-information)

Comment: Basically OpenGL will run on most platforms. Use opengl to inquire about gpu's

Comment: can I get more information about OpenGL?. Can you suggest some sample code just to display GPU information in a swing application.

Comment: For swing get lwjgl